# What is the linq query of below sql statements?

Tags: .net, sql-server, linq

Can anybody explain me how to write equivalent LINQ query for this SQL query

```
select  t1.Description,t2.Description,t1.ReponseTypeID 
from tblResponseType t1
   inner join tblPartnerServiceResponseType t2 
      on t1.ReponseTypeID = t2.ReponseTypeID
where t1.ReponseTypeID = (select ReponseTypeID
                          from tblPartnerServiceResponseType
                          where PartnerServiceID = 1);
```

I am new to this

Answer (score 0):

```
db.tblResponseTypeEntitieDB.Where(el => el.ResponseType.Id = 1).ToList()
```

Conditions:

- Relations are correctly filled in within your entity, ...

Also, we don't have much context...

Answer (score 0):

We can first try as two queries:

```
var psrt = tblPartnerServiceResponseType.FirstOrDefault(srt => srt.PartnerServiceID == 1);
if (psrt != null)
{
    var rt = tblResponseType.FirstOrDefault(rt => rt.ReponseTypeID == psrt.ReponseTypeID);
}
```

This will work, but requires two round-trip to the dataserver.

Ok, next, let's assume that you've got you foreign keys set up right, so that `tblPartnerServiceResponseType` has a tblResponseType property in it:

```
var query = from t2 in tblPartnerServiceResponseType
            where t2.PartnerServiceID == 1
            select new {Desc1 = t2.tblResponseType.description, 
                        Desc2 = t2.Description,
                        t2.ReponseTypeID
                        };
```

Finally, if you DON'T have the foreign key set up (which you really SHOULD!), then we have to do the explicit join:

```
var query = from t2 in tblPartnerServiceResponseType
            join t1 in tblResponseType on t2.ReponseTypeID equals  t1.ReponseTypeID
        where t2.PartnerServiceID == 1
        select new {Desc1 = t1.Description, 
                    Desc2 = t2.Description,
                    t2.ReponseTypeID
                    };
```